# How to re-order Record Types in Salesforce

Tags: record-type, sales-cloud

This has been a limitation for as long as I remember, where you cannot re-order Record Types in Salesforce. By default, it will be in alphabetical order.

The two most common workaround for this has been to either:

- Use a letter before the record type name, e.g A Record Type 1, B Record Type 2, etc
- Use a number before the record type name, e.g 1 Record Type 1, 2 Record Type 2, etc

Besides these two approaches, is there any other workaround that you have found and can share? Since neither of these two works for my client.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are probably aware you can translate Record Type names?! (I've just tried and apparently they still turn up in alphabetical order - according to the alphabet of the DeveloperName, not the translation. This gives some leeway regarding choosing DeveloperNames...)